# print order details pdf in order detail page

Tags: magento2.3, orders, pdf

I need to add a print button to the order detail page so once we click on it we have the same information in a downloaded pdf format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896592/is-it-possible-to-save-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: I need to do a magento extension